# python dict.fromkeys with function as parameter

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to group data from `test_input` with `classes`, i.e. if 2 values from `test_input` are the same, they should have the same class.

I've tried to create a dictionary but can't get how the class management can be done:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input,expected", [
    ([23,33,33,53,63,73,83,93,103], 'dictwithclass'),
])
def test_colorize(test_input, expected):    
    classes = ("colore1","colore2","colore3","colore4","colore5","colore6","colore7","colore8","colore9","colore10")

    insiemi=set(test_input)

    result = dict.fromkeys(insiemi, classi)
```

should output:

> {33: "colore1", 83: "colore2", 53: "colore3", 103: "colore4", 73:
>   "colore5", 23: "colore6", 93: "colore7", 63: "colore8"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dict.fromkeys()` will set all keys to a *the same, single value*. You can't use it to set to multiple distinct values.

Use `zip()` to pair up your keys and values, then pass the resulting sequence of `(key, value)` pairs to the `dict()` type directly:

```
classes = ('colore1', 'colore2', 'colore3', 'colore4', 'colore5', 'colore6', 'colore7', 'colore8', 'colore9', 'colore10')
result = dict(zip(set(test_input), classes))
```

Note that because `set()` objects are *unordered*, you won't know for certain what key goes with what class here. With integer values, that order is stable between invocations of the interpreter but *can* differ from Python version to Python version.

Demo:

```
>>> classes = ('colore1', 'colore2', 'colore3', 'colore4', 'colore5', 'colore6', 'colore7', 'colore8', 'colore9', 'colore10')
>>> dict(zip(set(test_input), classes))
{33: 'colore1', 103: 'colore2', 73: 'colore3', 83: 'colore4', 53: 'colore5', 23: 'colore6', 93: 'colore7', 63: 'colore8'}
```

The above assumes that there are never more that 10 unique keys; it may be better to *generate* the class names here:

```
result = {key: 'colore{}'.format(i) for i, key in enumerate(set(test_input), 1)}
```

This uses the `enumerate()` function to number each element in the set (starting at 1) and then using that number to generate a classname.